# Can someone describe APNs logic for me w/ re-establishing connection + knowing when to send?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Can someone describe the APNs architecture to me in regards to:

1. How does the handshake work when authenticating from server to client, for a push-notification?
2. How does the APNs know when to send a push-notification to a phone after it's been turned off (push notification would have been originally sent to the phone at that time).  Does the phone know to ping the APNs when it first boots up?

Answer (score 0):

Telecoms is complicated and has evolved over time. An APN is not exactly an internet domain. It is used to establish a PDP context which sets up a tunnel to the home provider to allow packets to be exchanged, this maybe an internet connection. The apn is a name to indicate which network your device is part of, the hlr/hss from the operator will know if your sim is provisioned for that apn. The sim does the mutual authentication between terminal and network, the sim has a identical chip as your payment-card. It contains a secret and logic to verify it knows that secret.

The network can wake up a non-transmitting device, this can be a data-sms, but there is also a signal to send a push to the terminal. The hlr/hss has a message waiting flag indicator, so a switched off device will receive an sms, just one that is processed invisibly and would actually pling on your phone.

As I said, telecoms is complicated so my explanation is more storytelling than reading 3gpp specs.